# Capturing WPF ComboBox Selections Into Variables In PowerShell

Tags: wpf, powershell, combobox

I'm building a GUI for a bit of PowerShell that will create resource mailboxes for the multi-site organization I work for.

There are two ComboBoxes in the form. The first `cboAgencies` is populated from a nested hashtable. [This one, actually.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44447772/704977) The second `cboOffices` populates with the locations for the Agencies selected in the `cboAgencies`.

Using `.Add_SelectionChanged()` as the event, I try to write the selected item to a variable and do a few other things, including query `hash_AgencyOffices` again using the newly selected criteria to populate the next ComboBox.

Here are the bits of the code important to this specific question:

```
$arr_Agencies = ($hash_AgencyOffices['Agency2','Agency1'].Keys | Sort-Object)
$arr_Agencies | ForEach-Object {
    $cboAgencies.Items.Add($_) | Out-Null
}

$cboAgencies.Add_SelectionChanged({
    $selectedAgency = $cboAgencies.SelectedItem.ToString()
})
```

The problem is, `$selectedAgency` never gets the selected item from `cboAgencies`. I can check $cboDivisons.SelectedItem and $cboAgencies.SelectedItem.ToString() and they both return the item selected in the UI correctly, but that value is not being passed to $selectedAgency.

I've tried with and without the .ToString() part, but that doesn't appear to make a difference.

I've also read a little bit on binding, but I'm still not sure whether or not that is the "correct" way to do this.

Comment: Try defining `$selectedAgency` in the parent scope first. Add `$selectedAgencies = ''` before your `$cboAgencies.Add_SelectionChanged` line, and see if that helps. You may be seeing scope issues.

Comment: That possibility passed through my browser tabs as I was researching this, and I've tested it, and it doesn't make a difference. But, it's good to know it's a good thing to do anyways in PS.

Comment: Ok, so I'll do some more reading on Scope. From the little I've read so far, the gist of Scope is that variables are limited in their effective area, and so if you want a variable to operate throughout a script with discrete sections, you'll have to set it up a particular way. It's been a good handful of years since I worked in VBA, but is this similar to global versus local variables there?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler is $cboAgencies.Add_SelectionChanged({}) considered a function? And should I define $selectedAgencies or $Script:selectedAgencies outside it?

Comment: $Script: pushes the balloon out of the glass dome. Got it. :) And it appears to be working too. The selected value is being handed off to the variable. If you'd like to write up your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Yea, that's what's happening now. Using the $Script: inside the function I'm seeing a list of the variables that exist in the script. Now I'm working on deciding which variables need to stay inside and which need to work outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comments into an answer:

You are likely to have scope issues; for a simple demonstration, this code:

```
$a = 1
function test { $a = 2 }

test
$a
```

will set a value for `$a`, make a function to change it, call the function, and then .. show that it hasn't changed. What happens is `$a = 2` makes a new variable called `$a` inside the function scope, sets it to `2`, then throws it away when the function exits.

In your code, try replacing with `$Script:SelectedAgency` to make it explicity update the outside variable ('script scope'). A demonstration for this is:

```
$a = 1
function test { $script:a = 2 }

test
$a
```

I haven't tried this analogy on anyone yet, but I'm thinking of a sci-fi landscape with glass domes (cities, parks, greenhouses, etc). If you float a variable-balloon outside, it goes up in the sky and everyone can see it (that's analogous to global or script scope). Go into a dome, look up, you see the balloon outside.

But if you try to float another balloon for everyone to see, it gets trapped by the glass roof. You look up and can see your local balloon overlaying/in front of the global one outside, so it looks almost the same to you, but other people in outside or in other domes cannot see it, they see the original one up in the sky. Unless you explicitly push your new one outside with `$script:` or `$global:`, then other people can see it too.

---

Annoying nuanced extension, you might head on and then trip over this:

```
$a = 1
$b = @(1,2,3)

function test {
    $a = 2
    $b[0] = 2
}

test
```

If you imagine what's on the balloons is a zipcode for the building where your stuff is, then people who see the balloon in the sky go to one building. People who see the balloon trapped on the roof of your dome blocking the outside one, can go to another building instead, which is more specific and relevant to them. But once you get to the building, you can move your stuff around.

So `$a = 2` is trying to float a new zip code balloon, and not everyone sees it. But `$b[0] = 2` is saying "go to the global zip code of `$b`, and *then* change the stuff around". Everyone who goes to the same building sees the change you made to the stuff, you didn't update the *name* `$b` itself, so there's no scope problem.

Comment: As TheMadTechnician suggested, I declared the variables outside the function at the head of my script `$selectedAgency = ''`, and as TessellatingHeckler noted I then reference them inside the function using `$Script:selectedAgency`.