# Trouble filtering a Nested Hashtable inside a Switch

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I've built a WPF form with 2 Combo Boxes, both filled with queries from this [Nested Hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44447772/704977).

`cboAgencies` fills when the script runs and the form loads. `cboOffices` based on the selection made in `cboAgencies` and lists the office locations specific to the selected Agency.

Or, it's supposed to.

Here's the relevant code:

```
$cboAgencies.Add_SelectionChanged({

    $Script:selectedAgency = $cboAgencies.SelectedItem.ToString()
    $Script:cboOffices.Items.Clear()
    $Script:selectedAdmin = $null

    Switch($Script:selectedAgency) {
        subdivision1 {
            $Script:selectedAdmin = 'division2'
            $Script:arr_Offices = ($Script:hash_AgencyOffices[$Script:selectedAdmin][$Script:selectedAgency].Keys | Sort-Object)
            $Script:arr_Offices | ForEach-Object {
                $Script:cboOffices.Items.Add($_) | Out-Null
            }
            break
        }
        subdivision2 {
            $Script:selectedAdmin = 'division2'
            $Script:arr_Offices = ($Script:hash_AgencyOffices[$Script:selectedAdmin][$Script:selectedAgency].Keys | Sort-Object)
            $Script:arr_Offices | ForEach-Object {
                $Script:cboOffices.Items.Add($_) | Out-Null
            }
            break
        }
        division1 {
            $Script:selectedAdmin = 'division1'
            $Script:arr_Offices = ($Script:hash_AgencyOffices[$Script:selectedAdmin][$Script:selectedAgency].Keys | Sort-Object)
            $Script:arr_Offices | ForEach-Object {
                $Script:cboOffices.Items.Add($_) | Out-Null
            }
            break
        }
    }
})
```

*Note: The code is anonymized. There are no spaces in the real division or subdivision names in the hashtable. Just in case that is a point of concern.*

Running this code using `. .\script.ps1` I query the various variables and find that the following variables are all correctly:

- `$cboAgencies.SelectedItem` *(and `$Script:cboAgencies.SelectedItem`)*
- `$selectedAgency` *(and `$Script:selectedAgency`)*
- `$selectedAdmin` *(and `$Script:selectedAdmin`)*

But $arr_Offices is empty, meaning that the problem is happening in this line:

```
$Script:arr_Offices = ($Script:hash_AgencyOffices[$Script:selectedAdmin][$Script:selectedAgency].Keys | Sort-Object)
```

I've further confirmed this by placing this outside the `Switch` function:

```
$Script:arr_Offices = ($Script:hash_AgencyOffices['division2']['subdivision1'] | Sort-Object)
$Script:arr_Offices | ForEach-Object {
    $Script:cboOffices.Items.Add($_) | Out-Null
}
```

And `$arr_Offices` and `$cboOffices` fill just fine.

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Ok, I think that's fixed it. I thought I'd tried it sans .Keys, which is why I don't have .Keys in the larger code sample, but apparently I had not. But I'm also a little confused. The array filling cboAgencies has to be filled using `$hash_AgencyOffices['division1','division2'].Keys` otherwise it just lists (Collection) twice. Why is .Keys necessary there and not inside the Switch function?

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. Well, the .keys bit was the solution I needed. Feel free to write that up and I'll accept it.

Comment: Cool; I've tried to copy it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your linked question, `$script:hash_AgencyOffices[$Script:selectedAdmin][$Script:se‌​lectedAgency]` results in an array of strings, it will not have a `.Keys` property.

Your data structure is "*Root hashtable which has keys, their values are hashtables, which have keys, their values are arrays which directly have content*".

So you can use `AgencyOffices['division2'].Keys` and `AgencyOffices['division2']['subdivision1']`, but not `AgencyOffices['division2']['subdivision1'].Keys`.